# Pycharm getting column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, traceback

I'm new into this coding world (like 2 weeks old) so I just ran into a problem. I was following a tutorial like most of us did in the begging. The task was to add a new column called "Month". To do that they suggest to take the 2 first numbers from the column called "Order Date". I wrote the code by letter from the tutorial, the only difference was that I was using Pycharm and they Jupyter Notebook. I like Pycharm so maybe someone knows how to solve this.

**The code is the following:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = [file for file in os.listdir("./Files")]
allmonths = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv("./Files/" + file)
    allmonths = pd.concat([allmonths,df])
alldata = pd.read_csv("allmonths.csv")

### Month Column addition
alldata["Month"] = alldata["Order Date"].str[0:2]
allmonths['Month']
print(alldata.head())
```

**The Traceback:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Coding\Sales_Data\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Order Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Coding\Sales_Data\Sales Anal.py", line 11, in 
alldata["Month"] = alldata["Order Date"].str[0:2]
File "D:\Coding\Sales_Data\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "D:\Coding\Sales_Data\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Order Date'

I know the problem is something about the column names, and maybe that Pycharm can't get it from the CSV file. But, HOW to solve it... IDK

Comment: The error suggests that there is no column named `Order Date` in your DataFrame. Can you verify there is a column with that name? You can print the column names with `print(alldata.columns)`.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the input data in an edit to your question?